# Access the values of a map in groovy?

Tags: groovy

I have the following class test:

```
class Main{

  private Map<String, SomeClass> someClass

}
```

and the SomeClass is as follows:

```
class SomeClass{

  private String number
  private Map<String, String[]> someClassMap     

}
```

I have a list of Main class:

```
def someList
List<Main> main = callSomeService

main.each { m ->
  def z = m.someClass.values().number
  def x = m.someClass.values().someClassMap.findAll{it.key == 'someValues'}   <-- problem
  if(x){
    someList << z       
  }
}
```

now what I want to do, in the main list I want to check if the key of the someClassMap equals to "someValues"
then put number in someList

any thoughts would be appreciated?

Comment: If you want to access the fields of `Main` and `SomeClass` you should not declare them private. You're relying on the ability to access a private member from outside the class, which is a bug in Groovy

Comment: @Don: a bug? really? I thought it was by design. Do you have a source for this?

Comment: @Joachim this is not by design. However, fixing this issue would break lots of code (like the above) that is exploiting this bug, so it is intended to fix this issue in Groovy 2.0 http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-3010

Comment: Thanks for the information, didn't know this. So is/was this an *implementation* bug or was it a bug in the way it was designed?

Comment: AFAIK, it was an implementation bug that was knowingly introduced when a new feature was added to Groovy.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
if (m.someClass["someValue"]) {
     someList << z
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def someList = []
someClassMap.each {key, value -> 
    if (key == 'someValues') {
        someList << value
    }
}
```